# Broadcast Receiver finish Activity without finishing all app

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have an android app with custom contacts list. I use Broadcast Receiver to catch when phone is ringing and then I started the Activity which display a information about caller from my contacts list from the app. Activity is not full screen.

My problem is when I using my app with another functionalities and somebody call to my. Then Activity with information is started and after end of calling i close this Activity with informations using finish() and my whole app is finished. I want to back to previous Activity/Screen and I don't know how to do it.

Is it possible to close only this Activity which shows informations?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();   
    //    finish();
}
```

or call:

```
onBackPressed();
```